# VSTS / TFS REST API - Fetch Work Items and their linked ones

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am retrieving some User Stories using the the [VSTS / TFS Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1) and the code below:

```
var getWorkItemsHttpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), uri + "/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=736,731&&api-version=4.1");
var getWorkItemsHttpResponse = client.SendAsync(getWorkItemsHttpRequestMessage).Result;

if (getWorkItemsHttpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{    
    var workItems = getWorkItemsHttpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpWorkItems>().Result;
    // ...
```

The query returns all the fields of the work items (user stories, in this case), but not the other items that is linked to them.
I would like to retrieve the Tasks related to these User Stories.

How can it be done ? 
Is there another better way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `$expand` parameter in the URL with the value `relations`:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/4?$expand=relations&api-version=4.1
```

In the results, you will get the work item links in the section `relations`:

```
"relations":[
 {
   "rel":"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
   "url":"https://dev.azure.com/shaykia/_apis/wit/workItems/5",
   "attributes":{
   "isLocked":false
}
```

In the example above, we check work item `4` in the API, and in the results, we can see that work item `5` linked to him with a type of `System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward` that work item `4` the parent of `5` (`5` he is the child, a task in this case).

You can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/link-type-element-reference?view=vsts) about the relations types.